# Clicking on UIButton added as subview to UILabel opens popup away from button.?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, popup

**hello Buddies , I have used UIButton as subview to UILabel and I m opening some popup on click of that button and I found that the popup is opening away from that button What is the reason behind it , Help Please.. Thank You!
My code is as follows:**

```
    sortBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [sortBtn setTitle:@"Sort" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [sortBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.137 green:0.384 blue:0.871 alpha:1.0]];
 [sortBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f]];
 [sortBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(sortTheData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  sortBtn.frame=CGRectMake(195,5, 53, 28);

 [categoryLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
 [categoryLabel addSubview:sortBtn];
```

**sorttheData Method is as follows:**

```
SortByController *sortController = [[SortByController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SortByController" bundle:nil];
sortController.dataArray = self.dataAllPerformances;
sortController.sortString =self.sortString;
sortController.genreId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.genreId];
sortController._delegate = self;
self.popController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:sortController];
//popController.delegate = self;
popController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(230, 260);
[popController presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
[sortController release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is you are adding your button in categoryLabel not in view while presenting the popover in self.view.

try following:

```
CGRect rect = [self.view convertRect:[sortBtn frame] fromView:self.view];
[popController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

this will get your button's frame in respect to self.view storing in rect type of CGRect (frame is also type of CGRect). Than while presenting popover pass this new rect in place of sender.frame as sender.frame has its x,y according to the categoryLabel.

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks  CGRect rect = [self.view convertRect:[sortBtn frame] fromView:categoryLabel]; is working ....